# Свертывание и развертывание окна

Tags: vb.net, winforms, окно

Скажите, пожалуйста, как свернуть и развернуть на весь экран Форму тобишь окно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized    'Развернуть на весь экран'
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized    'Свернуть на панель задач'
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal       'Обычный размер'
```